# How should I integrate flux into create-react-app?

Tags: flux, create-react-app, todomvc

I implemented flux on top of a create-react-app application using the flux [todomvc](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc) example as the point-of-departure:

1. AppView renders the create-react-app App component
2. AppContainer exports AppView (just like the todomvc)
3. index.js renders AppContainer (the todomvc uses root.js)

I'm wondering if that's the way to do it, or if it is better to rewrite the App functionality directly in AppView (in other words, get rid of the App component entirely).